# What is taking my SSD to 100% utilize with the extremely slow read speed?

Tags: firefox, ssd, performance

Recently, I found significant slowdown of my Firefox cold startup on my PC with SSD drive. Previously, my Firefox could cold start in less than 2 seconds. Now, it could take from 30 seconds to 1 minute.

When I check with Task Manager, this is what I saw:
[image]
From the image you can see that the SSD is utilizing 100% with average response time over 11 seconds and the read speed is less than 3MB/s.

When I run Google Chrome, the browser cold start in less than 2 seconds. The Task Manager there shows it does not even utilize 50% and the read speed is over 180MB/s.

This question here is not to ask about how to fix my Firefox. But, **what is taking my SSD to 100% utilize with the extremely slow read speed?**

Comment: Click processes and check/sort the disk tab at the top. See if anything is hogging the SSD.

Comment: Your question isn't able to be answered with the information you've provided.  The SSD make/model is required, as all SSDs are not created equally, as well as free space available _(10% of an SSDs total size should be configured for Over Provisioning)_, what process is being listed as using the most disk access percentage, and likely additional info I'm not thinking of